# Origin http://localhost.com:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin when trying to upload image to Cloudinary using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, cloudinary

I am trying to upload images to Cloudinary using my Angular controller. The requests are unsigned, and I am not using any libraries. Its just a simple POST request, **which worked when I tried it using jQuery on a static html page**.

Anyway, this is my controller:

```
myapp.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.uploadPicture = function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("upload_preset", "[MY UNSIGNED UPLOAD PRESET]");

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/[MY CLOUD NAME]/image/upload',
            data: formData,
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            alert(respose.secure_url);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
        });
    };

}]);
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/[MY CLOUD NAME]/image/upload. Origin http://localhost.com:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Why am I getting this error? Any help please. To repeat what I said before, this exact code written in jQuery worked perfectly on a static page called index.html, so I am kinda lost on the problem.

This is the jQuery code:

```
(function() {
        $('#uploadBtn').click(function() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

            console.log(file);

            formData.append("file", file);
            formData.append("upload_preset", "[MY UNSIGNED UPLOAD PRESET]");

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/[MY CLOUD NAME]/image/upload",
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function( response ){
                    alert(response.secure_url);
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });
        });
    })();
```

and

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<button id="uploadBtn">Upload</button>
```

All of the above was in a static html file called `index.html`.

Comment: looks like a server side error..is CORS enabled?

Comment: @suraj I believe it is, because as I said before, this worked with a static html page.

Comment: *"which worked when I tried it using jQuery on a static html page"* Show that code. Also, what was the **exact** source page URL containing that jQuery code when you did that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated post.

Comment: Again: What was the exact URL of that when you did the request?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using a browser *other* than Chrome and ran your "static HTML" page from the file system, not a web server process; e.g., from a `file://` URL rather than an `http://` URL (such as the `http://localhost:8000` of your Angular example).

Different browsers treat `file://` URLs differently. Some, like Chrome, conclude that **no** cross-origin call is valid with a `file://` URL (and that even other `file://` URLs cannot reliably be considerd the same origin), but some other browsers take a very different approach and consider `file://` URLs exempt from the Same Origin Policy entirely, allowing them to query anything.

So the difference isn't Angular vs. jQuery, the difference is `file://` URL vs. `http://` URL. All `http://` (and `https://`) URLs are subjected to the SOP by all browsers.

If I'm correct, the issue is that the service you're trying to post to doesn't allow the origin `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH";
$httpProvider.defaults.heade`enter code here`rs.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization";
```

I faced similar issue while running my app from local and get it resolved by adding these headers.